# How can i delete local storage data <key and value> from accounts.google.com

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, google-api-js-client

How can i  delete local storage data  from accounts.google.com . As it is from google domain we cannot access it via localStorage getItem or setItem , so is there a way to delete or clear this data from my accounts.google.com local storage , below is the image.

`localStorage.clear()`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5X0W.png)

Comment: it needs cors to go through, so if you manage to get past that, try this: `page=open('https://google.com');page.parent.localStorage.clear();page.close()`

Comment: Thanks for replying . I tried what you mentioned and also this . It dint work.                                                  
    var page=window.open('https://accounts.google.com');
    page.parent.localStorage.clear();
    page.close()  .  getting error as cannot read property clear undefined / localstorage undefined / parent undefined . Also i dont want another page to be opened and closed

Comment: Which type of browser are you on?

Comment: Chrome browser  . It is an electron desktop application , to that i integrated google sign in option . In that electron application chrome browser

Comment: Strange. It works for me somehow...

Comment: ok . i tried again , it din't work . Anyways Thank you